# mongoDB aggregation: find values on multidimensional array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Few days ago i was working with MongoDB and aggregation function, but i cant get results that i'm looking.

Suppose a collection that has a document like this:

```
[_id] => 2Q4YkrDUPIdMpHYdG7e801
[domain] => notedlinks.loc
[updateDate] => 1353582907
[pageCaches] => Array (
[0] => Array (
    [url] => 421341234213470dfb61366
    [data] => Array (
        [domain] => notedlinks.loc
        [url] => http://notedlinks.loc/sample/node
        [contentHash] => 382a250d4c226bb85b910c04d1774bb7a9020e44
        [percent] => 100
        [info] => Array (
            [results] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [tag] => Twitter
                    [url] => http://dbpedia.org/resource/Twitter
                    [references] => Array (
                        [0] => twitter
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        [updateDate] => 1353582907
    )
)
[1] => Array (
    [url] => 786527618a424234be70dfb61366
    [data] => Array (
        [domain] => notedlinks.loc
        [url] => http://notedlinks.loc/sample/node
        [contentHash] => 382a250d4c226bb85b910c04d1774bb7a9020e44
        [percent] => 100
        [info] => Array (
            [results] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [tag] => Twitter
                    [url] => http://dbpedia.org/resource/Twitter
                    [references] => Array (
                        [0] => twitter
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        [updateDate] => 1353582907
    )
)
)
```

Initially, for the search, i have: the colection,  _id value, and url value to search on.

The intention, is for a specific url, example: url: '786527618a424234be70dfb61366', to get the value of the "data" associated with that url, without load all document content. Get only:

```
 [data] => Array (
        [domain] => notedlinks.loc
        [url] => http://notedlinks.loc/sample/node
        [contentHash] => 382a250d4c226bb85b910c04d1774bb7a9020e44
        [percent] => 100
        [info] => Array (
            [results] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [tag] => Twitter
                    [url] => http://dbpedia.org/resource/Twitter
                    [references] => Array (
                        [0] => twitter
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        [updateDate] => 1353582907
    )
```

I have been using some forms but havent success results.
For example:

```
db.dm_2Q.aggregate({ $match: { _id : "2Q4YkrDUPIdMpHYdG7e801"}, $unwind : "$pageCaches", $project : {pageCaches: 1}, $match : {"pageCaches.url" : "786527618a424234be70dfb61366"}});

{
"result" : [
    {
        "_id" : "2Q4YkrDUPIdMpHYdG7e801",
        "pageCaches" : [
            {
                "url" : "786527618a42084367ccbe70dfb61366",
                "data" : {
                    "domain" : "notedlinks.loc",
                    "url" : "http://notedlinks.loc/sample/node",
                    "contentHash" : "382a250d4c226bb85b910c04d1774bb7a9020e44",
                    "percent" : "100",
                    "info" : {
                        "results" : [
                            {
                                "tag" : "Twitter",
                                "url" : "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Twitter",
                                "references" : [
                                    "twitter"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "updateDate" : 1353582907
                }
            },
            {
                "url" : "786527618a424234be70dfb61366",
                "data" : {
                    "domain" : "notedlinks.loc",
                    "url" : "http://notedlinks.loc/sample/node",
                    "contentHash" : "382a250d4c226bb85b910c04d1774bb7a9020e44",
                    "percent" : "100",
                    "info" : {
                        "results" : [
                            {
                                "tag" : "Twitter",
                                "url" : "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Twitter",
                                "references" : [
                                    "twitter"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "updateDate" : 1353582907
                }
            }
        ]
    }
],
"ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, i've found a solution:

```
db.dm_2Q.aggregate({$unwind: "$pageCaches"},
{$match:{ "pageCaches.url": "786527618a424234be70dfb61366"}}, 
{$project : {"pageCaches.data": 1}});

{
"result" : [
    {
        "_id" : "2Q4YkrDUPIdMpHYdG7e801",
        "pageCaches" : {
            "data" : {
                "domain" : "notedlinks.loc",
                "url" : "http://notedlinks.loc/sample/node",
                "contentHash" : "382a250d4c226bb85b910c04d1774bb7a9020e44",
                "percent" : "100",
                "info" : {
                    "results" : [
                        {
                            "tag" : "Twitter",
                            "url" : "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Twitter",
                            "references" : [
                                "twitter"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "updateDate" : 1353582907
            }
        }
    }
],
"ok" : 1
}
```